# realizar consulta y condicionar update

Tags: mysql, mariadb, condiciones

Concretamente ya probé un montón de cosas y no me sale o me hice lio de tanto intentar.

Tengo 2 tablas **Resumen** y **Detalle**

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es obtener todos registros para un DNI en la tabla DETALLE, sobre el resultado comprobar los valores de "pago_contado" y "regularizado", si se cumple que **todos** los registros tienen como valor **1** en cualquiera de los 2 campos se actualice el estado del DNI en la tabla RESUMEN.

Como lo hago?
Aclaro que estas tablas fueron creadas para el ejemplo con la idea de explicar lo mejor posible el concepto. Espero me entiendan lo que quise decirles jaja

## Tabla Resumen

[image: Tabla Resumen]

## Tabla Detalle

[image: Tabla Detalle]

## Ejemplo:

[image: Ejemplo]

Comment: que consultas has probado hasta ahora? si los valores son 0 o 1 yo lo plantearía onda sumar todos los valores y compararlo con el numero de registros sumados (esto es por cada grupo de dni)

Comment: Todo pinta a que va por ahí, tal cual!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nada mejor que hacer todo por pasos.. despacito..

Lo primero que vamos a hacer, es obtener los dni que cumplen las condiciones:

```
SELECT dni, max(pago_contado) as contado, max(regularizado) as regularizado
FROM detalle
GROUP BY dni
```

Esto nos va a devolver una tabla que tendra dni, el max encontrado en la columna pago_contado y el maximo encontrado en la columna regularizado.

Ahora, sobre esa consulta, la podemos filtrar para obtener los dni que realmente queremos, eso haciendo algo asi:

(llamemos A a la consulta anterior)

```
SELECT A.dni 
FROM A
WHERE contado + regularizado = 2
```

Porque ese where? porque si en una columna habia un 1, el max devolvio 1, y si los dos devolvieron 1, entonces la suma va a dar 2.

Ahora, si llamamos B a esa tabla, podriamos hacer el UPDATE de solo esos dni con algo asi

```
UPDATE resumen SET ESTADO="valido"
WHERE dni exists (B)
```

ahora, obviamente, podemos juntar todas las consultas

```
UPDATE resumen SET ESTADO="valido"
WHERE dni exists (
    SELECT A.dni 
    FROM (
        SELECT dni, max(pago_contado) as contado, max(regularizado) as regularizado
        FROM detalle
        GROUP BY dni)
    WHERE contado + regularizado = 2)
```

NOTA:

En toda esta explicacion, en realidad hay una query de mas, porque B puede suprimirse si en A se hace algo asi:

```
SELECT dni, max(pago_contado) as contado, max(regularizado) as regularizado
FROM detalle
GROUP BY dni
HAVING max(pago_contado) > 0 AND max(regularizado) > 0;
```

La idea de no hacer esto de entrada, fue explicarte bien la logica.

---

### Edicion:

el having, tiene que ser otra condicion entonces...

La consulta que trae los registros que cumplen deberia ser:

```
SELECT dni, min(pago_contado+regularizado) as cuenta
FROM detalle
GROUP BY dni
HAVING min(pago_contado+regularizado) > 0;
```

En estos casos, el registro que sume 0 no va a quedar, por lo tanto, ese dni va a quedar eliminado.

Comment: Entendí perfecto como lo explicaste, el tema es que no cumple mi necesidad.

El tema es que esta consulta me trae 2 registros(DNI) pero la realidad es que solo 1 de ellos esta cumpliendo la condición.

`SELECT a.dni FROM ( SELECT b.dni, max(b.pago_contado) as contado, max(b.regularizado) as regularizado 

FROM detalle b 

GROUP BY b.dni) a WHERE contado + regularizado = 2`

Comment: Perfecto. Esta mal lo que hice porque entendi mal.. ya lo hacemos de vuelta....

Comment: Con la corrección del Having funciona genial!! Gracias por la ayuda!!!
Es genial porque sin hacer subconsultas llegaste a lo que necesitaba hacer, gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

con la idea de @alo Malbarez y la logica de @gbianchi llegue a esto. Funciona

```sql
UPDATE resumen set estado = 'Validado' 

WHERE dni = (SELECT b.dni FROM (SELECT * , sum(a.pago_contado + 
a.regularizado) suma, count(*) contador FROM `detalle` a GROUP by a.dni) 

b WHERE b.suma = b.contador)
```

Comment: ¿Es posible que un registro tenga 1 en ambas columnas? En caso que así sea, ¿qué pasaría si tienes 4 registros donde los dos primeros tienen 1 en ambas colimnas y los otros 2 tienen 0?